# Set default date to today in 2amigos datepicker in yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to set today's date as default date (already selected) whenever the form loads. I'm using 2amigos datepicker widget.

Following is the code of my datepicker -

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'ss_date')->widget(
                    DatePicker::className(), [
                     'id' => 'datepicker1',
                     'inline' => false,
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'defaultDate' => date('Y-m-d'),
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',

                    ]
                    ]);
                    ?>
```

Following is the javascript that I'm trying

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var date = new Date();
    var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'}).val(today);
});
```

I'm not getting any error, but the date is not getting selected when the form loads.

Comment: In controller set `$model->ss_date = date('Y-m-d');`.  Simple :)

Comment: It was that simple and I spent almost 3 hours. Thank  you very much.